# Ubuntu 20.04 first http request is extremely slow

Tags: networking

I'm having a very weird behavior. I have a web app that makes an http request to an external API endpoint. This is taking extremely long, around 5 - 30 seconds when it's done or the first time. (On average, it's around 15 seconds.)

I'm currently on a fresh install of [PopOS 20.04](https://pop.system76.com/) which is basically Ubuntu 20.04, but the problem still exists. (EDIT: I have also tried this on Ubuntu 20.04 and have the same issue.) This is not a VPS. It's my laptop.

Here is what I noticed:

- The request is slow for the first time and subsequent requests are extremely fast. After a few minutes, the request becomes slow again, but only the first one.
- I don't any issues browsing websites on my browser. It's fast.
- I don't have this issue on Ubuntu 18.04.
- I tried using curl from Terminal to make the API request to simplify the scenario. This is significantly better, but still takes around 3 - 5 seconds on average. The same using Invoke-WebRequest from PowerShell on Windows is extremely fast (avg 300-400ms).
- When I connect to a hotspot created by iPhone, the request is extremely fast. It's slow on my home wifi. I tried this on a public network at my local library yesterday and it was also very slow. (This is biggest clue I have so far.)

My home wifi and the hotspot shared from my iPhone have around the same speed.

I have no idea why this happens. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pop!OS is not “basically Ubuntu” because System76 has gone and changed the boot mechanism, the DE, and a whole bunch of things under the hood, making the project a distinct operating system, and off-topic for this site. That said, you can ask this question [on Pop! Planet](https://pop-planet.info/), which is a forum dedicated to Pop!OS 

Comment: @matigo I tried the same scenario on Ubuntu 20.04 and have the same scenario, so it does apply here. I can probably modify my question.

Comment: OK, it seems to work if I change the DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `8.8.8.8`. It's currently set to `127.0.0.53`. Why does Ubuntu provide this as a default, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, It turns out to be a DNS server issue. I changed the DNS of my network to 8.8.8.8 (offered by Google). You can do this on Ubunte from Settings.

[image: Picture of Network settings on Ubuntu]